# Check if same genre exist in mysql database

Tags: javascript, mysql

Hi everyone I am new to mysql and would like to test if the same genre exist in a database and if it does it returns a status code and if the genre does not exist the genre is added into the database. I am currently having the following issues, it is able to check if the genre exist and return the status code but when entering a different genre it reacts the same way as if the genre exist :

file 1

```
Insertgenre:function(genre,description,callback){

        var dbConn=db.getConnection();
    
        // connects to the mysql database (contains an asyn function that returns a callback)
        dbConn.connect(function(err){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                return callback(err,result);
    
            }else{
                // Query for get all rows from genre table where genre = entered genre
                var checkSql = 'SELECT genre FROM genre WHERE genre = ?';
                
                dbConn.query(checkSql, [genre], function(err1, result) {
                    
                    if(err) {
                        return callback(err,result);
                    
                    }else {
                        // Checking if the result length is more than 0.
                         if(result.length > 0) {
                             return callback(err1,result);
                         }else {
                            var sql="insert into genre(genre,description) values(?,?)";
                            dbConn.query(sql,[genre,description],function(err,result){
                                  dbConn.end();
                            
                            if(err) {
                                console.log(err);
                            } 
                            return callback(err,result);
                            
                        }
                    }
                    }
                });
```

file 2

```
app.post('/genre', function(req,res){
    var genre = req.body.genre;
    var description = req.body.description;
    

    genreDB.Insertgenre(genre,description,function(err,err1,result){
        if(err){
            //console.log(err)
            res.type('json');
            res.statusCode=500;
            res.send(`{"Result":"Internal Error"}`);

        }if(err1){
            console.log(err1)
            res.type('json');
            res.statusCode=422;
            res.send(`{"Result":"The genre name provided already exists"}`);
        }
        else{
            res.type("json");
            res.statusCode=204;
            //res.send(result);
            console.log(result);
            res.send(`{"Affected Rows":"${result.affectedRows}"}`);
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Why does the title say "user" but the question says "genre"?

Comment: @Barmar sorry my bad , I’ll edit the title

Comment: Your callback function expects 3 arguments, but you only call it with 2 arguments.

Comment: Compare `function(err,err1,result)` with `callback(err,result);`. There are supposed to be two `err` arguments, and `result` should be the third argument.

Comment: Sorry may I know which line I should add the arguments to ?

Answer (score 0):

Your callback function expects `err` to be a normal database error, and `err1` to indicate that the genre already exists.

You need to call `callback()` with 3 arguments to match what it expects.

You also have a typo. In the second query, the callback function's argument is `err1`, but you used `if(err)`.

And in file 2, you should use `else if(err1)` since all these conditions are mutually exclusive.

```js
Insertgenre: function(genre, description, callback) {

    var dbConn = db.getConnection();

    // connects to the mysql database (contains an asyn function that returns a callback)
    dbConn.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return callback(err, false, result);

      } else {
        // Query for get all rows from genre table where genre = entered genre
        var checkSql = 'SELECT genre FROM genre WHERE genre = ?';

        dbConn.query(checkSql, [genre], function(err1, result) {

            if (err1) {
              return callback(err1, false, result);

            } else {
              // Checking if the result length is more than 0.
              if (result.length > 0) {
                return callback(null, true, result);
              } else {
                var sql = "insert into genre(genre,description) values(?,?)";
                dbConn.query(sql, [genre, description], function(err, result) {
                    dbConn.end();

                    if (err) {
                      console.log(err);
                    }
                    return callback(err, false, result);

                  }
                }
              }
            });
        });
    })
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for the response ! I have edited the code but it still shows that the genre exist after entering a new genre

Comment: `if(err1)` in file 2 should be `else if(err1)`.

Comment: You had a typo in the second query, its error check should be `if (err1)`.

Comment: I have made the changes and the new genre has been added but the status code does not reflect

Comment: While using postman to send the POST request it gets stuck at "sending request" but the new genre still gets added to the database

Comment: Hi I think I have solved the issue ! Apparently by adding the line ```res.send(`{"Affected Rows":"${result.affectedRows}"}`);``` it fixed the issue which reflects the status code 204

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't create JSON by hand like that. Use `res.send(JSON.stringify({"Affected Rows": result.affectedRows}))`

Comment: I see, Thank you very much for all the help ! appreciate it :)